# android Service не работает

Tags: java, android, android-service

имеется класс `SyncActivity`в котором есть функция `test()`, нужно чтоб эта функция выполнялась в фоновом режиме периодически, создал службу, но почему - то ничего не работает, если я правильно понял, то служба прерывается в момент создания переменной `SyncActivity s = new SyncActivity();`, т.к при удалении этой строчки служба нормально работает (в логи выводится значения i из цикла), от чего это может быть?

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
* Created by Admin on 18.03.2016.
*/

public class SyncService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public SyncService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Служба создана", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Служба создана");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Служба запущена");
    someTask();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Служба остановлена");
}
void someTask() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "сработал someTask");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 1;
            SyncActivity s = new SyncActivity();

            while (true) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i);
                i++;
                s.test();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Синхронизировано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

Comment: А что за SynkActivity и что у неё в конструкторе?

Comment: это то что отвечает за синхронизацию, а конструкторе ничего его нет

Comment: в этом активити есть кнопка при нажатии на которую вызывается функция `test` для синхронизации, мне нужно это функцию вывести в службу чтоб каждый раз не заходить в меню и не нажимать на эту кнопку

Comment: Ну... А если test сделать статическим?... Пока что проблема не очень понятна.

Comment: не могу сделать его статическим, много ошибок появляется в коде, который внутри это метода

Comment: Вообще из сервиса создавать экземпляр активити - странная идея. Активити не создала разметку и вообще... это странно.

Comment: а можно в сервисе как то имитировать нажатие кнопки из другой активити?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Но что вам мешает код перенести в сервис?..

Comment: не получается перенести этот код туда, я копи пастил появляются новые ошибки, там внутри этого метода используются много других методов (non static) поэтому не  могу сделать его static(((

Comment: В таком случае не знаю как вам помочь. Неужели копипаст всех нужных методов не получается?..

Comment: нет не помог копипаст , спасибо(